# SiriSpeechErrorDomain log message when entering an empty dictation message in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nslocalizedstring

I've noticed that throughout our app whenever we use the dictation button on the keyboard to enter text in a `UITextView` and then press done without saying anything the following two lines appear in our logs:

```
!!! _NSLayoutTreeGetBaselineOffsetForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index 0
Localizable string "SiriSpeechErrorDomain" not found in strings table "Error" of bundle CFBundle 0x15fd54b50 </System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework> (framework, loaded).
```

A search for `"SiriSpeechErrorDomain"` yielded 0 results on google. Where are these log messages coming from and is this indicative of a potential issue?

I did a quick check by breakpointing in the `textViewDidChange:` delegate function of the `UITextView` and I got the following result:

First call of function immediately after hitting "Done" without dictating text:

```
p textView.text
(NSString *) $9 = 0x0000000178258240 @"\U0000fffc"
```

Second call of function:

```
p textView.text
(NSString *) $10 = 0x0000000197305980 @""
```